# Find m ,belonging to real numbers, such that the logarithm is defined.

Tags: inequality, logarithms

The problem goes like this:

Find all $m \in R$ such that:

$\lg[(m+3)x^2-(m+4)x+4+m]$
exists for any $x>0$.

I did  the condition of existence of the logarithm:

$(m+3)x^2-(m+4)x+m+4>0$ and $m+3>0$

after resolving the two inequations I got $m \in (-\infty,-4)\bigcup(-\frac{8}{3},\infty) \bigcap(-3,\infty)$ ,which is equivalent with $m \in(-\frac{8}{3},\infty)$.

The problem that I am facing is $x>0$. I do not know how to put the conditions for m such that $x>0$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see $(+3)^2−(+4)++4$ as a quadratic equation in $x$ that represents a U-shaped parabola (i.e. it has a minimum). In order for this to be greater than zero we need to ensure that the quadratic has no real solutions. We should therefore be able to apply the condition $b^2<4ac$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are coefficients of the standard quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: Well yes,I did apply that when I resolved the inequation,but the thing is the U-shaped parabola has a part where x is negative,and the problem says that x>0.

Comment: The parabola is symmetric and therefore, I believe, the solution you have is sufficient.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much!